# R googleway bug in geocoding with address

Tags: r, geocode, googleway

I have some problem with the google_geocode function in googleway package. At first I've just tried it with a simple address:

```
key <- MyKey

df <- google_geocode(address = "5 Rue J-F Kennedy 8332 Luxembourg",
                     key = key,
                     simplify = TRUE)
```

And got the following message:

```
Error in value[[3L]](cond) : 
There was an error downloading results. Please manually check the following URL is valid by entering it into a browswer. If valid, please file a bug report citing this URL (note: your API key has been removed, so you will need to add that back in) 
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?&address=5+rue+j-f+kennedy+8332+luxembourg&key=
```

I'd pasted it to my browser, and it was OK. Any idea?

Comment: Are you behind a firewall (e.g. on a company or uni network)?

Comment: yes, so in this case what can I do?

Comment: Ah, I see you've already asked for help - https://github.com/SymbolixAU/googleway/issues/187 - have you tried these suggestions?

Comment: thanks, it's working now with sys.setenv function and https